# Bug in glossaries package while using hyperref?

Tags: hyperref, page-numbering, glossaries

I compile the following code:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[
    bookmarks=true,
    bookmarksopen=true,
    colorlinks=true,
    anchorcolor=blue,
    filecolor=blue,
    citecolor=black,
    urlcolor=black,
    linkcolor=black,
    menucolor=blue,
    breaklinks=true
]{hyperref}
\usepackage{glossaries}

\makeglossaries


\newglossaryentry{symb:band_energy}{
name=\ensuremath{\epsilon_k},
description={Band energy in momentum space}
}

\title{Title goes here}
\author{Me of course}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\pagenumbering{Roman}
\blindtext
\clearpage

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\blindtext
We will refer to the band structure as \gls{symb:band_energy}.

\printglossary[style=index]

\end{document}
```

The problem is, when clicking in the pdf on the page number given in the glossary (which is the correct one), one will end up on the title page! Is this a bug or did I miss something? I'Ve been reading about problems with `hyperref` and `glossaries` but this wasn't mentioned anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The title page is numbered as well (page 1). But you can't see it. So I would suggest, you set the roman page numbering to the very beginning and it works. You will then have the second page numbered as "II" which is just right in my opinion.

```
% arara: lualatex
% arara: makeglossaries

\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{symb:band_energy}{%
    name=\ensuremath{\epsilon_k},
    description={Band energy in momentum space}
}

\title{Title goes here}
\author{Me of course}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{Roman}
\maketitle
\blindtext
\clearpage

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\blindtext
We will refer to the band structure as \gls{symb:band_energy}.

\printglossary[style=index]

\end{document}
```